Does there exist a graph product that corresponds with the direct product on groups? What about other group extensions?
More specifically:

Is there a graph product $*$ such that for all graphs $G$ and $H$, we have $\text{Aut}(G) \times \text{Aut}(H) = \text{Aut}(G * H)$, where $\times$ denotes the direct product on groups?

I think the answer is probably no, because graph products and group extensions feel like entirely different beasts, but I don’t really know how to think about a problem like this. (I learned from my question earlier today that each group has a graph with that automorphism group, by Frucht’s theorem, but I don’t know how to apply that here.)
Thanks for your insight!

You can use the tensor product of graphs but the automorphism group could be a bit larger (index 2 extension), if the graphs are isomorphic. But this is inevitable for any natural product construction.

Semidirect product doesn't make much sense - which action do you use that is always available? What other "group extensions" (?) do you mean? Please clarify. Also, do you require that $$ is a functor? (You should, otherwise it's indeed a consequence of Frucht's theorem.) What other requirements do you have for $$?

@MartinBrandenburg Removed semidirect product from the question as you made me realized it didn’t make much sense. As for the graph product, I’m going by the Wikipedia definition, which states “it is an operation that takes two graphs G1 and G2 and produces a graph H with the following properties:
The vertex set of H is the Cartesian product V(G1) × V(G2), where V(G1) and V(G2) are the vertex sets of G1 and G2, respectively.
Two vertices (a1,a2) and (b1,b2) of H are connected by an edge, iff a condition about a1, b1 in G1 and a2, b2 in G2 is fulfilled.”
